# Send email from admin in cartridge orders

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, cartridge

I am using the **cartridge with django for my shop** , I **want to send email** from the **admin when I change the order status from the admin**![image: Send Email]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with admin in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235041/issues-with-admin-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to have a look at the Django docs for [overriding the save method on a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects).

Then check the Django docs for [sending email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/email/).

(That's a assuming there's no email functionality bundled with Cartridge - I don't know Cartridge and couldn't immediately tell - obviously you could confirm this by reading the [docs](http://cartridge.jupo.org/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is **no email functionality bundled** with **Cartridge admin** on **order status**